# ImportError: No module named dm.xmlsec.binding

Tags: python, saml, xmlsec

I am trying to implement SAML2.0 in my Django(version 1.7) application in Python 2.7 by using oneLogin python-saml library (https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml), but I am getting this error below:

```
import dm.xmlsec.binding as xmlsec
ImportError: No module named dm.xmlsec.binding
```

When I tried to install this specific library on my machine I am getting this error:

```
Collecting dm.xmlsec.binding
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/56/30/7d19e02398b46593c7a72589c767c50f1ff4a96845f5bc6c61c3183fb213/dm.xmlsec.binding-2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: cannot get XMLSec1 pre-processor and compiler flags; do you have the `libxmlsec1` development package installed?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-W3sKpb/dm.xmlsec.binding/
```

Please, let me know what libraries should I use to implement SAML2 in python2.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Installation section](https://github.com/onelogin/python-saml#installation), that package has some external dependencies:

> ### Dependencies
>
> - python 2.7
> - [dm.xmlsec.binding](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dm.xmlsec.binding) Cython/lxml based binding for the XML security library (depends on python-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev)
> - [isodate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isodate) An ISO 8601 date/time/duration parser and formater
> - [defusedxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/defusedxml) XML bomb protection for Python stdlib modules

For `dm.xmlsec.binding`, you need to install `libxmlsec1-dev`.

Depending on your platform:

- Debian/Ubuntu

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install libxmlsec1-dev
  ```
- OS X (using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/))

  ```
  $ brew install libxmlsec1
  ```

Then install the dependency

```
$ pip install dm.xmlsec.binding

OR

$ python -m pip install dm.xmlsec.binding
```

(*Make sure to install it in the same `python` env as your application*)

Answer (score 0):

open terminal and hit the below command

```
pip install dm.xmlsec.binding
```